# Get values from List without know the names of variables

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm having some troubles and I would like to know how to resolve them.
Is possible to get values from object of Anonymous Type without know the name of vars?

I have 2 comboboxs:

```vb
With combobox1
  .ItemsSource = list1
  .DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
  .SelectedValuePath = "Age"
End With

With combobox2
  .ItemsSource = list2
  .DisplayMemberPath = "Address"
  .SelectedValuePath = "Number"
End With
```

I want to get values from the selected combobox but I want a gerenic sub:

```vb
Dim list As New List(Of Object)

Private Sub FilterCombobox(combobox as Combobox)
  For Each item In combobox.Items
    list.Add(New With {.Value = item.????,
                       .Display = item.????})
  Next
End Sub
```

How I can call the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath on the For Each?

```vb
.Value = item.SelectedValuePath 
.Display = item.DisplayMemberPath
```

[image]

[image]

I want to access this values but as you can see, the item names are different.
I need to access this data dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using reflection:

```
Private Sub FilterCombobox(combobox As ComboBox)

    If combobox IsNot Nothing And combobox.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Dim type = combobox.Items(0).GetType()
        Dim displayMemberPath = type.GetProperty(combobox.DisplayMemberPath)
        Dim selectedValuePath = type.GetProperty(combobox.SelectedValuePath)

        For Each item In combobox.Items
            List.Add(New With {.Value = selectedValuePath.GetValue(item),
                       .Display = displayMemberPath.GetValue(item)})
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! This is what I was looking for.